# jQuery find the most inner content

Tags: jquery, regex, dom, jquery-selectors, selector

I want to find the inner content OR text for each element situated at end of DOM, and replace with it to `<span class="red">content</span>`

This is what I am using

```
regex = new RegExp("\\b"+word+"\\b", "gi");

$(this).find("*:not(:has(*))").each(function(){
    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(
        regex, function(matched) {
            return "<span class=\"" + className + "\">" + matched + "</span>";});
});
```

but the problem here is, if the structure is `<div>one two</div>`, after word `one` is replaced to `<div><span class="red">one</span> two<div>` now my selector cannot find the second `two`

Please look into the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jpWaw/) here `two` is not getting highlighted

Comment: are you looking for `<span class="red">one two</span>` or `<span class="red">one</span> <span class="red">two</span>` ?

Comment: See the fiddle, I am looking for `<span class="red">one</span> <span class="red">two</span>`, because after first iteration my div structure goes as `<div><span class="red">one</span> two<div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need is

```
var words = ['one', 'two'];
var regex = new RegExp("\\b(" + words.join('|') + ")\\b", "gi");
$('#outer').find(":not(:has(*))").html(function (idx, html) {
    return html.replace(regex, '<span class="red">$1</span>');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Xga8p/)

The problem is, once the loop is executed the `myId` element will have a span element as the child because `one` is replaced with `<span class="red">one</span>` which causes your selector `*:not(:has(*))` to fail

Comment: Yes that was the problem, but I could not understand that how your method solved this.
The problem was my selector (the `*` before the selector) or my regex?

Comment: Ok got the point, I go for the for loop and second time it can not find the content, but your regex replaces every word in one iteration.

Comment: @Akshay yes... you got it

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
var words = ['one','two'];
regex = new RegExp("\\b("+words.join('|')+")\\b", "gi");
$('#outer').find("*:not(:has(*))").each(function(){
     this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(regex, function(matched) {
          return "<span class=\"red\">" + matched + "</span>";
     });
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/jpWaw/1/